# How can I create a numpy matrix from another?

Tags: python

I have a numpy matrix with 10 columns and 4 rows filled only with 0 and 1.
I want to modify only the first row using slices.

```
mat = [[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
       [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

slices like a point in the middle so the row becomes

```
[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]
```

and the rest of the matrix is equal to the previous one.

I tried to use these slices but I don't know how to put them together.

```
mat1 = mat[0,0:5]
mat2 = mat[0,5:10]
```

Comment: `np.concatenate((mat2, mat1))`?

Comment: I think it's not very clear what you are trying to do, can be more specific? `mat[0,0:5]` is an array ( the first five elements of the first row)

Comment: Hi @UlisesBussi , I'm trying to slice the original first row of the matrix, in mat1 and mat2, put them together (mat2 then mat1) and having a new matrix with only the first row changed reversing the two half. I have done in that way because I don't know any other method to do it.

Comment: I understand now! you want to change only the first row, yep, then you can concatenate or `hstack` the slices do: `newRow =  np.hstack( [ mat[0,5:], mat[0,:5] ])` then add the new row to original matrix (or a copy if you want to keep the original one).

Other choice is to define a vector with new indices `newOrd =[5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4]` and do ` mat[0,:] = mat[0,newOrd] `

Comment: @not_speshal ok, now how can I put this row as my first row in the mat?

Comment: `mat[0] = np.concatenate((mat2, mat1))`